# Copy column from table 1 to table 2 and copy their content

Tags: sql, sql-server

im comparing 2 tables.
Table 1 with columns 1-5.
Table 2 with columns 1-6.

how to add the 6th column(from table2) with full content in the table1

Comment: You need to be more specific about the database engine that you are referring to. This information can be provided in tags, the one you have used is ambiguous. It is also a good idea to attach tables diagram to clarify.

Comment: Im Using Ms sql 2014 and hat 5 columns of type varchar.

Comment: I will quote the sql tag description : " [..] Questions should include code examples, table structure, sample data [..]". It would be much easier for  someone to give you an accurate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how that could be achieved:

```
DECLARE @FirstTable TABLE (
    FirstFirst VARCHAR(5),
    FirstSecond VARCHAR(5),
    FirstThird VARCHAR(5),
    FirstFourth VARCHAR(5),
    FirstFifth VARCHAR(5))
INSERT INTO @FirstTable
VALUES 
    ( '111', '121', '131', '141', '151' ),
    ( '112', '122', '132', '142', '152' ),
    ( '113', '123', '133', '143', '153' )

DECLARE @SecondTable TABLE (
    SecondFirst VARCHAR(5),
    SecondSecond VARCHAR(5),
    SecondThird VARCHAR(5),
    SecondFourth VARCHAR(5),
    SecondFifth VARCHAR(5),
    SecondSixth VARCHAR(5))
INSERT INTO @SecondTable
VALUES 
    ( '111', '121', '131', '141', '151', '161' ),
    ( '112', '122', '132', '142', '152', '162' ),
    ( '113', '123', '133', '143', '153', '163' )

--As a join
SELECT ft.*, st.SecondSixth FROM @FirstTable AS ft
LEFT JOIN @SecondTable AS st ON 
    ft.FirstFirst = st.SecondFirst AND
    ft.FirstSecond = st.SecondSecond AND
    ft.FirstThird = st.SecondThird AND
    ft.FirstFourth = st.SecondFourth AND
    ft.FirstFifth = st.SecondFifth

--As outer apply
SELECT ft.*, oa_secondTable.SecondSixth FROM @FirstTable AS ft
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 st.SecondSixth FROM @SecondTable AS st
    WHERE 
        ft.FirstFirst = st.SecondFirst AND
        ft.FirstSecond = st.SecondSecond AND
        ft.FirstThird = st.SecondThird AND
        ft.FirstFourth = st.SecondFourth AND
        ft.FirstFifth = st.SecondFifth
) AS oa_secondTable
```

Short description
- Two tables
-- First example there is comparison with joining
-- Second example theres is comparison with outer apply